# MLE for Parameter Estimation using Mathematica

Tags: mathematica, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

I am using Mathematica (MMA) 10.0.0.0 with MathStatica do determine parameters using MLE for several PDFs. I have tried the approach below for several PDFs but I keep getting messages that Mathematica & MathStatica cannot analytically solve for the parameters. Although this may indeed be the case, I can solve for some analytically. So I think I may have some issues with my MMA code.

As an example, let $X_1,...X_n$ be i.i.d random variables from the hyperbolic secant distribution with location and scale parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$:

\begin{equation*}
 f(x|\mu,\sigma) = \frac{1}{2\sigma} sech\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)I_{(-\infty,\infty)}(x)
\end{equation*}

I was able to show (analytically) that $\tilde{\mu}$ and $\tilde{\sigma}$ are respectively:

\begin{equation*}
\tilde{\mu} = \bar{X}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\tilde{\sigma} = \sqrt{\bar{X_n^2}-\left(\bar{X_n}\right)^2}
\end{equation*}

If I run the following MMA code with MathStatica addon I do not get this (for readability, `\[Sigma]` and `\[Mu]` are replaced by `sigma` and `mu`):

```
f = 1/(2 sigma) Sech[(Pi (x - mu))/(2 sigma)];
domain[f] = {x, -Infinity, Infinity} && {sigma > 0};
logLc = Log[Product[(f /. x -> Subscript[x,i]), {i, 1, n}]]
score = Grad[logLc, mu]
solc = Solve[score == 0, mu]
Hessian[logLc, mu] /. solc
```

I receive the following output:

[MMA Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW3Ci.jpg)

I suspect I am missing something or I am having issues since I am dealing with multiple parameters. I did try removing the location parameter and trying that for this example but I am still getting the issue.

Recall that I am trying to figure out why this does not work in this instance because I am planning to use this code for a couple more distributions. Therefore I cannot just use the mean and variance commands in MMA.

Comment: What is $I_{(-\infty, \infty)}$?

Comment: Also, pictures of code is really quite unhelpful. If you want us to debug code, please post… well, code, rather than pictures.

Comment: Should this be moved to Mathematica SE?

Comment: $I_{(-\infty,\infty)}(x)$  is the indicator function.

Comment: Subscripts are bad for indexing in Mathematica, for various reasons [1]. Is there any reason you are using `Subscript[x, i]` instead of `x[i]`? [1]: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94294/what-are-the-requirements-for-a-well-behaved-indexed-variable-subscript-toexpr

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
Variance[SechDistribution[m, s]]
Mean[SechDistribution[m, s]]
```

Comment: This will only work for this distribution. There are several other distributions I am working with where the parameters are not the mean and the variance.